# Error Segmentation Fault Core Dumped in C - Ubuntu

Tags: c, ubuntu

I am facing this error. I have searched on Internet and that solution is passing two arguments in main, argc and argv. I dont know why to use it and how i use it?
My program is to read a file that contains integers and print them

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int no;
    char ch;
    FILE *ftr;
    ftr = fopen("numbers.txt", "r");
    while ((ch = fgetc(ftr)) != EOF)
    {
        no = ch - '0';
        printf("%d", no);
    }
    fclose(ftr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: check what is returned by `fopen`

Comment: If `"numbers.txt"` is not where it has to be, then it explains what happened. Check that `ftr != NULL`.

Comment: what is the link with arguments? (you found on the internet)

Comment: numbers.txt is present in same directory but now it gives garbage values

Comment: @coderredoc fopen is just a function used to open file

Comment: @Fatima.: Yes it is a function...

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi  I have checked. File is not null but gives garbage values

Comment: Garbage value? What did you try when you say *I've checked*?

Comment: Low hanging fruit: `char ch;`  -->> `int ch;`, for a start...

Comment: Before processing as a number check the character type using [isdigit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isdigit).

Answer (score 1):

The only explanation for this is that `ftr == NULL`, try

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    FILE *file;
    char chr;

    file = fopen("numbers.txt", "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open the file\n");
        return -1;
    }

    while ((chr = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
        fprintf(stdout, "%d", chr - '0');
    }

    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: maybe display the strerror() so that we can figure out what went wrong

Comment: @Fatima I did not say that it would give correct output as I don't know what the file contains or what you are expecting from the program. But certainly, this would solve the SEGMENTATION FAULT.

Comment: My file contains 1 2 3 and it gives 1 - 382 - 383 - 38

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should check file opening and close by using the same level of checking as employed by these two snippets.

```
f = fopen(filename,"r");
if (f == NULL) {
    fprntf(stderr, "fopen failed: %s", strerror(errno));
    // and terminate the file IO here
}
..
..

if (fclose(f) == EOF) {
    fprint(stderr, "fclose failed");
}
```

Comment: FYI I downvoted your answer, because `int errno;` is not needed here, `#include <errno.h>` and perhaps `errno = 0;` somewhere (*if you know that it was probably modified by some call*)  or `extern int errno;` which MUST be global and is therefore automatically initialized to `0`. Also it seems that you don't understand that code is written for humans, not compilers. If compilers were more important then no one would invent a programming language which is basically a very small subset of the english language, compilers don't understand english.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi.: Yes `errno` need not be initialized. Would you suggest a way to improve this answer?

Comment: You need to at least be consistent with yourself. If you put a whitespace around operators (which you should) ALWAYS DO THAT, if you don't like that then don't put them, BUT DO SO ALWAYS.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi.: Thanks for the feedback...and I will try to write a better answer.